# Uncomment a line in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm getting into Puppet, and loving it, but am hitting my head against a wall with one small thing which I'm sure must be easier than I'm making it.

I wish to uncomment this line in the `.bashrc` of a user:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

I've been using augeas for lots of things, but it seems as though that won't work with this.

I note that there's a `file_line` resource which I can use to ensure a line is present in a file, but I need the line to remain in the same place.

I don't wish to replace the `.bashrc` entirely with my own copy, despite seeing that this pattern is popular in Puppet, it just doesn't make sense to me as I don't want to maintain my own version between upgrades.

In sed I use this:

```
sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" ~/.bashrc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just add your sed command to an exec with an unless option using grep. Something like this (untested):

```
exec { 'force_color_prompt':
  command   => 'sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" .bashrc'
  cwd       => '/home/user',
  shell     => true,
  unless    => 'grep -Fxq "force_color_prompt=yes" .bashrc',
}
```

Or use the file_line resource you mentioned (part of the Puppet Labs stdlib module I believe) to add the line uncommented and leave the commented line untouched.

Comment: You're my hero, thank you!

Can't just add the line, as location within the script is important, but your suggestion is great.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, file_line will replace a line that matches the regex.

So to get `force_color_prompt=yes` vs. `#force_color_prompt=yes` you could:

```
file_line {
    'color_prompt':
        path        => '/home/<youruser>/.bashrc',
        match       => 'force_color_prompt',
        line        => "force_color_prompt=yes",
}
```

Importantly, if the regex *matches*, the replace happens **in** place, ie. it will change the line, not the location of the line.  If the regex does *not* match however, the line will be appended to the end of the file.

This experience is with Puppet 3.1.

Reference: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib

Answer (score 1):

The [shellvar](http://augeasproviders.com/documentation/examples.html#shellvar-provider) already can uncomment lines

```
shellvar { '.bashrc':
  ensure    => present,
  target    => "/home/${your_user}/.bashrc",
  variable => 'force_color_prompt'
  uncomment => true,
}
```

I perceive this much cleaner than using exec and calling sed.

Answer (score 0):

While Augeas alone cannot do it, the `shellvar` provider from Augeasproviders will be able to do it, whenever [this PR](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeasproviders/pull/46) is merged.